# How to change URL by changing state

Tags: reactjs

I have one parent and two children. I'm trying to change the image url, by pressing the button, but no success... I cannot seem to pass data from the button-child to the image-child..

Parent:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isHidden: true,
      imageUrl: ""
    };
  }
  showImage = () => () => {
    this.setState({
      imageUrl:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/19/04/58/coconut-trees-4946270_960_720.jpg"
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ImageButton onClick={this.showImage()} />
        <Image />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

ButtonChild:

```
export default class ImageButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.showImage}>New image</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

ImageChild:

```
export default class ProfilePicture extends Component {
  render() {
    return <img src="{props.imageUrl}" />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, notice to a few changes. I hope that it will help you.

Parent:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isHidden: true,
      imageUrl: ""
    };
  }

  showImage = () => () => {
    this.setState({
      imageUrl:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/19/04/58/coconut-trees-4946270_960_720.jpg"
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ImageButton clicked={this.showImage()} />
        <ProfilePicture imageUrl={this.state.imageUrl} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

ButtonChild:

```
export default class ImageButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.clicked}>New image</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

ImageChild:

```
export default class ProfilePicture extends Component {
  render() {
    return <img src={this.props.imageUrl} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I always need to pass data from a child to the parent, in order to reach other siblings? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Yes, you should use a props-from-top-to-bottom and change-handlers-from-bottom-to-top approach.
try read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), Good luck!